# parseInt using strings while finding different operators

Tags: java

I am having issues with the things the title suggests. I need to tokenize the string, determine the operation in order to solve it, convert the numbers into `int` types and return the expression.

What exactly am I doing wrong as far as the parsing and tokenizing goes? Everything seemed ok until I tried to use the stringSplit. The only allowed library functions are `Integer.parseInt()` and `split()`. There are quite a few things on StackOverflow to help, but none that do not utilize only these two library functions. Here is the code I have thus far:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String a[] = {"12 + 34", "56 - 78", "99 * 99", "10 / 3"};
    stringSplit(a, ',');
}

public static int parseInt(String a)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    double x = Integer.parseInt(a);

    for(i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
        sum = sum + x;

    System.out.printf("%s = %d\n", sum);
}
```

The end result should look something like:

12 + 34 = 46.00

56 - 78 = -22.00

And the like. I am not really looking for the answer. More of a lead to my answer. Thank you in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Code for `stringSplit` method is missing..

Comment: And as the error indicates, you are missing a return statement in `parseInt`. The method should either have a return statement, or you should make it `void` instead of `int`. Please fix these basic errors and ask a specific question. Your current question is all over the place and it is hard to find a specific question in it.

Comment: @AniketKulkarni Thanks! I am looking into that now in order to properly use the method.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My return statement question was answered and fixed. Simple mistake I did not spot and was happy your eye caught it! The only other thing that had a question mark in my post was "What exactly am I doing wrong as far as the parsing and tokenizing goes?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working version of what you seemed to be attempting to do.  I split each element of your input array on space (`" "`), and then extract out two operands and an operator.  I also put in a check for dividing by zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String a[] = {"12 + 34", "56 - 78", "99 * 99", "10 / 3"};
    stringProcess(a);
}

public static void stringProcess(String[] a) {
    for (int i=0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        String[] parts = a[i].split(" ");
        double operand1 = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
        String operator = parts[1];
        double operand2 = Double.parseDouble(parts[2]);
        double result = 0.0;

        switch (operator) {
            case "+":
                result = operand1 + operand2;
                break;

            case "-":
                result = operand1 - operand2;
                break;

            case "*":
                result = operand1 * operand2;
                break;

            case "/":
                if (operand2 == 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Divide by zero!");
                }
                result = operand1 / operand2;
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(operand1 + " " + operator + " " + operand2 +
            " = " + String.format( "%.2f", result));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
12.0 + 34.0 = 46.00
56.0 - 78.0 = -22.00
99.0 * 99.0 = 9801.00
10.0 / 3.0 = 3.33
```

Comment: Very nice! However, as this is homework, I will see if I can find another way past case statements. Thank you good sir! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[] = { "12 + 34", "56 - 78", "99 * 99", "10 / 3" };
        parseInt(a);
    }

    public static void parseInt(String[] a) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            String[] pieces = a[i].split(" ");
            if("+".equals(pieces[1])){
                sum = Integer.valueOf(pieces[0]) + Integer.valueOf(pieces[2]);
            }else if("-".equals(pieces[1])){
                sum = Integer.valueOf(pieces[0]) - Integer.valueOf(pieces[2]);
            }else if("*".equals(pieces[1])){
                sum = Integer.valueOf(pieces[0]) * Integer.valueOf(pieces[2]);
            }else {
                sum = Integer.valueOf(pieces[0]) / Integer.valueOf(pieces[2]);
            }
            System.out.println("sum" + sum);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
As per method syntax.
<Access specifier><modifier><return type><method name>(arguments). If you are giving int as return type your method should return a value, else make the return type as void if you do not need any return value.
```